# Unit test directive error - Attempted to assign to read only property

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, sinon

Unit test directive error - Attempted to assign to read only property

**Tech**: Angular version 1.3 and javascript with sinon

This is the error I get in Git Bash:

[image]

**This is the code I'm testing:**

```
 angular.module("myApp.directives")
    .directive("checkList", ["lodash", function(lodash) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                filter: "="
            },
            templateUrl: "templates/components/check-list.html",
            link: function (scope, element) {
                scope.changeDetection = () : void => {
                    const listOfStrings = [];

                    lodash.forEach(scope.filter.options, function(option) {
                         if (option.selected) listOfStrings.push(option.name);
                    });

                    scope.filter.value = listOfStrings.length > 0 ? listOfStrings.join(",") : [];
                };

                scope.$watch("filter", (newValue, oldValue) => {
                    if (newValue) scope.changeDetection();
                } , true);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

**This is my unit test:**

```
"use strict";

describe("check list component:", function () {
    var rootScope;
    var element;
    var scope;
    var mockFilter = {
        "id": "underOffer" ,
        "value": [],
        "options": [
            {"Yes" : "Lease", "selected": false},
            {"name" : "No", "selected": false},
            {"name" : "Partial", "selected": true}
        ]
    };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp.directives"));
    beforeEach(module("ngLodash"));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        var rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = "<check-list filter=\"'" + mockFilter + "'\" ></check-list>";
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        angular.element(document.body).append(element);

        scope.$digest();
        scope = element.isolateScope();

        scope.filter = mockFilter;
    }));

    it("should call changeDetection and add value to check list", function () {
        //Arrange
        var mockResponse = "Partial";

        //Act
        scope.$digest();

        //Assert
        expect(scope.filter.value).toEqual(mockResponse);
    });
});
```

**Note**: Seems to be the watcher causing this issue. I basically want to stub is or ignore it somehow so I can test the changeDetection function.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Version of Angular is 1.3